# Control a recurring detection task using asynchronous or concurrent techniques in python

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, python-asyncio

I am working on a detection tool and I want to be able to control it over the web.  The web service should support the tool to start and stop and modify the detection configuration. But I don't know how to make the service and the tool work in parallel, because the detection tool is constantly cycling through the detection.

I have some knowledge about web and asynchronous. But those methods I know are
about "block and wait for all parallelizable tasks to finish at the end", but my probing tasks are supposed to be executed constantly after activation, which makes me confused.

I have written a small example to exemplify this：

```py
from typing import Optional, List

from fastapi import FastAPI, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel

config = {}
should_detecting = False
is_detecting = False
config_changed = False


def detect_task():
    global is_detecting
    global config_changed

    while should_detecting:
        is_detecting = True
        result = do_time_consuming_detect(config)
        if should_detecting and not config_changed:
            send(result)
        config_changed = False
    
    is_detecting = False


@app.get(root_route + "/detect")
def do_detect(start_flag: int):
    global should_detecting

    if start_flag == 1 and is_detecting != True:
        should_detecting = True
        execute_asynchronously(detect_task)
    elif start_flag == 0:
        should_detecting = False
    return {}

@app.get(root_route + "/update_config")
def update_config(new_config: dict):
    global config_changed
    
    config_changed = True
    config.update(new_config)
    return {}
```

So I would like to know how to make this web service work in parallel with detect_task(). Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. Because fastAPI provides the BackgroundTasks function, all you have to do is to put the tasks in.

```py
def detect(flags, ips):
    flags['is_detecting'] = True
    while flags['should_detect']:
        do_some_detect()
    flags['is_detecting'] = False

@app.get(root_route + "/detect")
def read_detect(start_flag: int, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    if start_flag == 1 and not flags['is_detecting']:
        flags['should_detect'] = True
        background_tasks.add_task(detect, flags, detecors)
    elif start_flag == 0:
        flags['should_detect'] = False
    return {}
```

The flags and detecors are simply global variables that are passed into the task as parameters.